# How to have a button in a form post to a different action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Let's say I have a form listing some items:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "SagePayServerInframe", FormMethod.Post))
{
    if (Model.Tokens.Any())
    {
        <h2>Select an existing card</h2>
        for (int i = 0; i < Model.Tokens.Count; i++)
        {
            <div class="sagepay-wrapper">
                <div><span>Card Type:</span> @Model.Tokens[i].CardType</div>
                <div><span>Last 4 Digits:</span> @Model.Tokens[i].Last4Digits</div>
                <div><span>Expiry Date:</span> @Model.Tokens[i].ExpiryDate</div>
                <div>
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.SelectedTokenId, Model.Tokens[i].Id, new { @id = "SelectedTokenId" + i })
                    <label for="SelectedTokenId@(i)">SELECT</label>
                </div>
            </div>            

        }
    }
    <input type="submit" value="Continue" class="uppercase"/>
}
```

Now, I want to put a Delete button against each entry as well. I can't seem to have another form within the existing form (it wouldn't show on the page when I tried a new `Html.BeginForm`).

How would I achieve this? Ideally, I'd like to be able to post back to a `DeleteToken` action. I get the feeling I'm missing something simple but not sure what it is.

Comment: You can have multiple forms, they just cant be nested. You could have a second loop after the first form - `foreach(var token in Model.Tokens) { @using (Html.BeginForm(.... new { id = Model.Tokens[i].Id })) { <input type="submit" ../> )`

Comment: Another option would be to use ajax to post to a Delete action (with the advantage the user stays on the same page and can continue to delete others)

Comment: Hm, the AJAX call might be the best one in this case then.

Comment: Knew I was being a simpleton. I can just have a hyperlink to remove the card ... sigh. Just woke up after a 36 hour working period, guess brain needed to engage :)

Comment: Not a good idea. An action that deletes something (i.e. changing data) should always be a POST, not a GET It will be added to the browser history and of course a user can just navigate to it so at best your just making an unnecessary database call to delete something that no longer exists and at worst may throw an exception depending on your code

Comment: Fair point. I've got enough validation in place so it won't cause an error but good point about browser history. Will change, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a Jquery hack like (Code not tested, may have syntax error, sorry for that)

When button1 is pressed, access the form object and reset the form url.

```
$("#button1").click(form(){
    $(this).form.URL = "../Controller1/Action1";
});
```

AND when button2 is clicked

```
$("#button2").click(form(){
    $(this).form.URL = "../Controller2/Action2";
});
```